# SQL: Insert multiple row with common columns

Tags: sql, insert, multiple-columns

I have a table into which i will insert and it has 4 columns. 
While inserting 3 columns will be same and the other one column will be different for each and it will be taken from another table.
How could i do that?
For exmaple;
INSERT INTO sendMsg (Type,Name,SenderName,Message) values(4, 'john','Mike','Hi, blabla')

i will insert same message also for Bob, instead of john.
and the names which i will send are contained in Names table.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a select statement to build up your insert. Something like this could work (as you didn't provide more details):

```
INSERT INTO sendMsg (Type,Name,SenderName,Message) 
SELECT 4, "name" ,'Mike','Hi, blabla' FROM anothertable
-- WHERE ....
```

Column names are in ", so don't be confused. It's to ensure difference between string and database object. 
Inside optinal WHERE you could do maybe something like

```
WHERE name in ('Bob', 'John', ...)
```

or whichever algorithm you need to determine the names.